# Common Backlog in TFS

Tags: tfs

I moved from Jira to TFS. In TFS Source code for multiple projects are stored. I can only see the option to create work items against a project. This then appear in the project backlog. I need to have a common backlog for all these projects. Cant see such an option. The version I am using is
Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Version 16.122.27102.1

What is the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the only way would be to have one big project in which you are than working with Teams.
Here is a Microsoft example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/multiple-teams?view=vsts

Comment: Chrizzo is right, you can't open work item that related to more than one team project. you can use TFS with only one team project and work with Areas and Teams.